# jQuery Push text into arrays

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple div like this

> ```
> <div class="main">
> <a href="/tohref.html">Category1</a>
> <div class="cat_id">1111</div>
> </div>
>
> <div class="main">
> <a href="/tohref.html">Category2</a>
> <div class="cat_id">1222</div>
> </div>
>
> <div class="main">
> <a href="/tohref.html">Category3</a>
> <div class="cat_id">1333</div>
> </div>
> ```

I want to get all a[href] text and div.cat_id text push into an array like this.

> ```
> [["category1","1111"],["category2","1222"],["category3","13333"]]
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/3rrpsvqs/2/

**JS:-**

```
var arr=[];
jQuery(function($){    
    $(".main").each(function(){
        var categoryName = $(this).find("a").text();
        var categoryValue = $(this).find(".cat_id").text();
        arr.push([categoryName,categoryValue]);
    });

    console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
});
```

**Log Output:-**

```
[["Category1","1111"],["Category2","1222"],["Category3","1333"]]
```

Comment: Thanks, This solution is working and easy to understand!

Answer (score 1):

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o8qdv2Ls/2/

Code:

```
var my_array = new Array();   
var my_array1 = new Array(); 
$('div').each(function(){  
  my_array[''+$(this).attr('id')+''] = $(this).text();   
  my_array.push($(this).text());        
});
$('a').each(function(){
  my_array1[''+$(this).attr('id')+''] = $(this).text();
  my_array1.push($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Hi, Your solution is also great! Thanks , but it didn't meet my criteria!